# scon portable and cleaner way for debug and release build together

Tags: python, build, scons

SConstruct : This file is implemented to use build library for debug and release build.

variant_dir is set to build/debug for debug build
             & set to build/release for release build

```
import os
env = Environment()

releaseEnv = env.Clone(CCFLAGS = ['-O3'])
debugEnv   = env.Clone(CCFLAGS = ['-O0', '-g'])

debugDirPath   = os.path.join('build', 'debug')      # build/debug
releaseDirPath = os.path.join('build', 'release')  # build/release

if os.name == 'nt':
    releaseEnv.Replace(CCFLAGS = ['EHsc'])
    # windows specific flags
    debugEnv.Replace(CCFLAGS = ['EHsc', 'Zi', 'MTd'])

SConscript(dirs = 'src', name = 'SConscript', exports = {'env' : releaseEnv}, variant_dir = releaseDirPath, duplicate = 0)
SConscript(dirs = 'src', name = 'SConscript', exports = {'env': debugEnv}, variant_dir = debugDirPath, duplicate = 0)
```

SConscript: (present inside source directory which contains a1.cpp and b1.cpp)

```
import os
Import('env')

src_list = Glob(os.path.join(Dir('#').abspath,  'src', '*.cpp'))

env.SharedLibrary(target='sum', source= src_list)
env.StaticLibrary(target='sum', source= src_list)
```

Directory structure is like:

```
 root_dir -> SConstruct
          -> src
               -> SConscript
               -> sum.cpp
               -> mul.cpp
```

1) Running scons from root_dir generates following warning and although it's a warning message build is stop, library doesn't gets created.

scons: *** Two environments with different actions were specified for the same target: /home/xyz/temp/src/mul.os
File "/home/xyz/temp/src/SConscript", line 7, in

> > > > > This issue has been resolved after using src_list = Glob('*.cpp');

2) What is the proper (portable) way to create environment object for debug and release build ?
  The way I have implemented is it correct ?

Kindly suggest necessary changes to avoid the warning and running build successfully.

Comment: That is not a warning, it is an error. It doesn't know how to build the file, because it has been given two different ways to build it

Comment: @TomTanner So what is the solution for it ? Can you please rectify the error and help me in fixing it ?

Comment: You should be using variantDir() to set up the build variants. See http://www.scons.org/wiki/VariantDir%28%29

Comment: @TomTanner Another option for variant_dir is to pass as SConscript argument, which I already did in my example... The problem here is src_list is generated from explicit path.. If I use src_list = Glob('*.cpp') then first error is resolved. Now I am seeking for the advise regarding second query...

Comment: Looks like you answered your first question.  You're method of creating Environment()'s is reasonable. though you could just create one with the CFLAGS and the clone it and set those CFLAGS to the second value. So only 2 Environments instead of 3.

Answer (score -1):

Your problem is not related to build variants, but the fact that you have two targets with the same name (`SharedLibrary` and `StaticLibrary` both build `sum`).

To fix that, either just give one of them another name or add an extension to at least one of them. If you add an extension, you might want to check for OS if you want to keep your cross-platform compatibility.

Comment: it's not complaining about that - it's complaining about mul.os